# Cómo generar Diccionario de Datos en SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo la siguiente consulta que lo encontré por internet pero tengo problemas para agregar el campo de la llave foránea que me indicará si el campo lo es. También quería agregarle un campo al final con nombre `dafault`, que me indique en caso tuviese uno asignado el valor por defecto que se cargaría si no se llenase nada a la hora de ejecutar el `insert`.

Por último quisiera saber por que el `where`tiene tamaña condición, es decir ¿Por que tiene que diferir de algunos `data_types`?

```
SELECT  distinct
        b.name  TABLA,
        c.name  COLUMNA,
        isnull(a.value,'')  DESCRIPCIÓN,
        e.name  TIPO,
        case when c.colid = 1 then 'PRIMARY KEY' else '' end    [PRIMARY KEY],
        c.LENGTH    TAMAÑO,
        case when c.isnullable = 1 then 'SI' else 'NO' END  NULLEABLE

FROM    sysobjects b 
        inner join syscolumns c 
            on  b.id = c.id 
        join sys.systypes e 
            on  c.xtype = e.xtype 
        left join sys.extended_properties a 
            on  a.major_id = b.id and 
                a.minor_id = c.colid 

WHERE   b.type = 'U' and b.name ='I_ATENCION' and e.name<>'NOMBRES' AND        e.name<>'ENTERO' and  
        e.name<>'FECHA' AND  e.name<>'MES' AND  e.name<>'MONEDA' and e.name<>'NOMBRES' and 
        e.name<>'OBSERVACIONES' and e.name<>'RFC' and e.name<>'STATUS' and e.name<>'TITULOS' and 
        e.name<>'TRESCHAR' and e.name<>'CHAR2' and e.name<>'CLAVELARGA' and e.name<>'CURP' and 
        e.name<>'comentarios' and e.name<>'VARCHARN' and   e.name<>'ID_T' and   e.name<>'bit' and   e.name='ID_C'

ORDER BY b.name,e.name
```

Answer (score 4):

Para este caso, te recomiendo que te olvides del código que encontraste en Internet ya que esa consulta es muy espcecífica para cierta solución. Lo primero es enterder la definición de **Diccionario de datos**, según [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diccionario_de_datos) es la siguiente:

> Un **diccionario de datos**, o repositorio de metadatos, como lo
>   define el *IBM Dictionary of Computing*, un repositorio centralizado
>   de información sobre datos tales como significado, relación con otros
>   datos, origen, uso y formato.

Ahora, lo siguiente consulta te puede entregar un diccionario de datos de forma muy general como el nombre de la `Tabla`, el nombre del `Campo`, `Tipo de dato`, `Valor por defecto` y si es o no `Requerido`:

```
SELECT 
    T.name AS Tabla,
    C.name as Campo,
    TP.name + '(' + CAST(TP.max_length AS VARCHAR) + ')' AS 'Tipo de Campo',
    (CASE 
        WHEN C.is_nullable = 0 THEN 'NULL'
        WHEN C.is_nullable = 1 THEN 'NOT NULL'
    END) AS 'Valor por defecto',
    (CASE 
        WHEN C.is_nullable = 0 THEN 'NO'
        WHEN C.is_nullable = 1 THEN 'SÍ'
    END) AS 'Requerido'
FROM SYS.TABLES T
    INNER JOIN SYS.COLUMNS C
        ON T.OBJECT_ID = C.OBJECT_ID
    INNER JOIN sys.types TP
        ON C.user_type_id = TP.user_type_id
ORDER BY T.name, C.name
```

Si se llegara a requerir algún dato extra, revisamos la forma en que lo podamos agregar.

Nota: la forma en que definimos el diccionario de datos no incluyo ningún `WHERE`, como tal no es necesario, a menos que desees filtrar la información que te muestra la consulta (*justo para eso sirven los `WHERE` de la consulta que encontraste en Internet*)

Comment: Gracias, sí, estaba tratando de armar la consulta desde cero, pero se me complica agregarle tres campos, aunque el campo que me indica el FK lo entiendo y hay varios ejemplos, pero no sucede lo mismo con los PK's.

Ahora con respecto al campo `Valor por defecto` de tu ejemplo me parece que se trata sobre si un campo admite `null` o no (también lo necesito) pero con `Valor por defecto` me refería a la condición de campo `DEFAULT` si es que lo tiene poner el valor, sino dejar en blanco. El campo `Requerido`no lo entiendo. También necesitaba el campo `Comentario` aunque lo puedo encontrar.

Comment: En resumen me gustaría saber como se podría agregar a esa estructura del `FROM` los campos: `PK`, `FK`, `DEFAULT`. Estos campos los tengo que llenar con "si" y "no". En caso del último campo le tengo que poner su "valor por defecto" (Si es que tiene uno). Los demás los puedo hallar con los esquemas "sys".

Comment: De acuerdo, dame unos momentos para ver qué podemos hacer al respecto :)

Answer (score 2):

Esta consulta puede servir, muestra el `nombre del esquema`, `nombre de la tabla`, `nombre del campo`, `tipo de dato`, `longitud del tipo de dato`, `indicador de llave primaria y foránea` y la `descripción del campo`.

```
SELECT S.NAME AS [SCHEMA_TABLE], 
       T.NAME AS [TABLE NAME], 
       C.NAME AS [COLUMN NAME], 
       P.NAME AS [DATA TYPE], 
       CASE C.max_length 
         WHEN -1 THEN 'MAX' 
         ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, C.max_length) 
       END AS [SIZE], 
       CASE c.is_nullable 
         WHEN 0 THEN 'No Nulo' 
         ELSE 'Nulo' 
       END AS [Nullable], 
       CASE c.is_identity 
         WHEN 0 THEN '' 
         ELSE 'PK' 
       END AS [PK], 
       CASE 
         WHEN ( fk.object_id IS NULL ) THEN '' 
         ELSE 'FK' 
       END AS [FK], 
       Isnull(sep.value, '') [DescriptiON] 
FROM   sys.objects AS T 
       JOIN sys.columns AS C ON T.object_id = C.object_id 
       JOIN sys.schemas AS S ON T.schema_id = S.schema_id 
       JOIN sys.types AS P ON C.system_type_id = P.system_type_id 
       LEFT JOIN sys.extended_properties sep ON C.object_id = sep.major_id AND C.column_id = sep.minor_id AND sep.NAME = 'MS_DescriptiON' 
       LEFT JOIN (sys.foreign_keys fk 
                  INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fc ON ( fk.object_id = fc.constraint_object_id )) 
              ON ( ( fk.parent_object_id = C.object_id ) 
                   AND ( fc.parent_column_id = C.column_id ) ) 
WHERE  T.type_desc = 'USER_TABLE' 
       AND s.NAME <> 'dbo' 
ORDER  BY s.NAME, 
          T.NAME, 
          c.column_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT identity(int,1,1)AS 'ROW_INDEX',schema_name(T.schema_id)  'SchemaName' ,name,object_id
INTO #TMP_TABLAS
FROM sys.tables T
where name in (
'tu tabla'
,'tu tabla'
,'tu tabla'
,'tu tabla'
)
DECLARE @INDEX INT=1,@LENGTH INT=0,@OBJECT_ID INT,@TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(100),@SCHEMA_NAME VARCHAR(100)
SET @LENGTH=(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM #TMP_TABLAS)
WHILE @INDEX<=@LENGTH
BEGIN
    --1.
    SELECT @OBJECT_ID=object_id,@TABLE_NAME=name ,@SCHEMA_NAME=SchemaName
    FROM #TMP_TABLAS WHERE ROW_INDEX=@INDEX
    SELECT @SCHEMA_NAME+'.'+@TABLE_NAME AS 'TABLA'
    --2.
    SELECT
    --T.object_id,T.name,C.object_id,
    --(CASE WHEN I.object_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'PK'
    --       WHEN FK.constraint_object_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'FK'
    --      ELSE '' END) 'REF'
    (CASE WHEN PK.column_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'PK'
           WHEN FK.constraint_object_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'FK'
          ELSE '' END) 'REF'
    ,C.name 'COLUMNA'
    ,TD.name 'TIPO'

    ,(CASE WHEN UPPER(TD.name) in ('VARCHAR','NVARCHAR','CHAR','NCHAR','TEXT') THEN (CASE WHEN C.max_length<0 THEN 'MAX' ELSE '['+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),C.max_length)+']' END)
           WHEN UPPER(TD.name) in ('DECIMAL') THEN '['+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),C.precision)+','+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),C.scale)+']'
           ELSE ''
      END
           )'TAMAÑO'
    ,(CASE WHEN C.is_nullable=1 THEN 'SI' ELSE 'NO' END) 'NULO'
    ,ISNULL(P.value,'') 'DESCRIPCION'

    from sys.tables T
    inner join sys.columns C on T.object_id=C.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.types TD ON C.system_type_id=TD.system_type_id AND TD.name!='sysname'
    --LEFT JOIN sys.index_columns IC ON C.object_id=IC.object_id AND C.column_id=IC.column_id
    --LEFT JOIN sys.indexes I ON IC.object_id=I.object_id AND I.is_primary_key = 1
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT IC.OBJECT_ID,IC.column_id
        FROM sys.indexes AS I
        INNER JOIN sys.index_columns AS IC ON i.OBJECT_ID = ic.OBJECT_ID AND I.index_id = IC.index_id
        WHERE I.is_primary_key = 1
        AND IC.OBJECT_ID=@OBJECT_ID)PK ON C.column_id=PK.column_id

    --LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE PK ON C.name=PK.COLUMN_NAME AND PK.TABLE_NAME=T.name
    LEFT JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns as FK ON T.object_id=FK.parent_object_id AND FK.parent_column_id=C.column_id
    left join sys.extended_properties P on C.object_id=P.major_id and C.column_id=P.minor_id
    where T.object_id=@OBJECT_ID--T.name='paginaweb_elemento'
    ORDER BY C.column_id
    --3.
    SET @INDEX=@INDEX+1
END
DROP TABLE #TMP_TABLAS
```

Comment: se te agradece la intención de ayuda pero responder con solo código se considera de baja calidad, por favor lee [answer], edita y explicalo

Comment: Gracias por responder y ayudar a la comunidad, pero para que tu respuesta se considere de buena calidad, debes explicar un poco lo que expones en tu código para que se entienda bien

Comment: Saludos si bien es cierto el codigo podria dar con la solución es mejor detallar como tu respuesta soluciona el problema planteado, gracias.